# How to iterate a list of list for a scatter plot and create a legend of unique elements

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

**Background:**

I have a `list_of_x_and_y_list` that contains `x` and `y` values which looks like:

```
[[(44800, 14888), (132000, 12500), (40554, 12900)], [(None, 193788), (101653, 78880), (3866, 160000)]]
```

I have another `data_name_list` `["data_a","data_b"]` so that

- `"data_a" = [(44800, 14888), (132000, 12500), (40554, 12900)]`
- `"data_b" = [(None, 193788), (101653, 78880), (3866, 160000)]`

The `len` of `list_of_x_and_y_list` / or `len` of `data_name_list` is > 20.

**Question:**

How can I create a scatter plot for each item (being the same colour) in the `data_name_list`?

**What I have tried:**

```
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
   ax = plt.axes(facecolor='#FFFFFF')
   prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
   colors = prop_cycle.by_key()['color']

   print(list_of_x_and_y_list)
   for x_and_y_list, data_name, color in zip(list_of_x_and_y_list, data_name_list, colors):
       for x_and_y in x_and_y_list,:
          print(x_and_y)
          x, y = x_and_y
          ax.scatter(x, y, label=data_name, color=color) # "label=data_name" creates 
                                                         # a huge list as a legend! 
                                                         # :(


       plt.title('Matplot scatter plot')
       plt.legend(loc=2)
       file_name = "3kstc.png"
       fig.savefig(file_name, dpi=fig.dpi)
       print("Generated: {}".format(file_name))
```

**The Problem:**

The legend appears to be a very long list, which I don't know how to rectify:

[image]

**Relevant Research:**

- [Matplotlib scatterplot](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-scatterplot/)
- [Scatter Plot](https://python-graph-gallery.com/scatter-plot/)
- [Scatter plot in Python using matplotlib](http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/scatter-plot-in-python-using-matplotlib/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a long repeated list as a legend is because you are providing each point as a separate series, as `matplotlib` does not automatically group your data based on the labels.

A quick fix is to iterate over the list and zip together the x-values and the y-values of each series as two tuples, so that the `x` tuple contains all the x-values and the `y` tuple the y-values.

Then you can feed these tuples to the `plt.plot` method together with the labels.

I felt that the names `list_of_x_and_y_list` were uneccessary long and complicated, so in my code I've used shorter names.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_series = [[(44800, 14888), (132000, 12500), (40554, 12900)],
               [(None, 193788), (101653, 78880), (3866, 160000)]]
data_names = ["data_a","data_b"]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax = plt.axes(facecolor='#FFFFFF')
prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
colors = prop_cycle.by_key()['color']

for data, data_name, color in zip(data_series, data_names, colors):
    x,y = zip(*data)
    ax.scatter(x, y, label=data_name, color=color)
    plt.title('Matplot scatter plot')
    plt.legend(loc=1)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: not too sure what does the asterisk does in `zip(*data)` but, thanks for your clear explanation! :)

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call) for an explanation of the asterisk :)

Answer (score 1):

To only get one entry per data_name, you should add data_name only once as a label. The rest of the calls should go with `label=None`.
The simplest you can achieve this using the current code, is to set data_name to `None` at the end of the loop:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from random import randint

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_facecolor('#FFFFFF')
# create some random data, suppose the sublists have different lengths
list_of_x_and_y_list = [[(randint(1000, 4000), randint(2000, 5000)) for col in range(randint(2, 10))]
                        for row in range(10)]
data_name_list = list('abcdefghij')
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
for x_and_y_list, data_name, color in zip(list_of_x_and_y_list, data_name_list, colors):
    for x_and_y in x_and_y_list :
        x, y = x_and_y
        ax.scatter(x, y, label=data_name, color=color)
        data_name = None
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Some things can be simplified, making the code 'more pythonic', for example:

```
for x_and_y in x_and_y_list :
    x, y = x_and_y
```

can be written as:

```
for x, y in x_and_y_list:
```

Another issue, is that with a lot of data calling `scatter` for every point could be rather slow. All the x and y belonging to the same list can be plotted together. For example using [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/):

```
for x_and_y_list, data_name, color in zip(list_of_x_and_y_list, data_name_list, colors):
    xs = [x for x, y in x_and_y_list]
    ys = [y for x, y in x_and_y_list]
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, label=data_name, color=color)
```

`scatter` could even get a list of colors per point, but plotting all the points in one go, wouldn't allow for labels per `data_name`.

Very often, [numpy](https://numpy.org/) is used to store numerical data. This has some advantages, such as vectorization for quick calculations. With numpy the code would look like:

```
import numpy as np

for x_and_y_list, data_name, color in zip(list_of_x_and_y_list, data_name_list, colors):
    xys = np.array(x_and_y_list)
    ax.scatter(xys[:,0], xys[:,1], label=data_name, color=color)
```

[image: sample plot]